# Filling multiple input fields with a javascript string

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible create a javascript string that, when manually copied and pasted to another web page, will paste information across multiple [input fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) at the same time?

For instance, suppose a webpage has two input fields. I cannot edit the webpage html, but I can type into the input fields. I can also paste information in, using Ctrl-V or the like.

I have another webpage, which I can edit. The javascript for my webpage creates a string such as `"Input for in1 here \t Input for in2 here"`. That string is presented through `window.prompt(myString)`. I copy `myString` from the prompt (Ctrl-C), switch to the other webpage with input fields, and paste the string (Ctrl-V). How can I format my string so it pastes across both input fields?

Is it possible to format the string (`myString` in the example here), so that it will do this?

Obviously `"\t"` won't work for this. Same for `"\n"`, etc.

Basically, I'm trying to create a helper for data entry. One web page would have the helper javascript. The other page (not in the same domain) would have multiple data input fields.

The data input page does not have an API hook.

Comment: You can try using a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead of an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: @Oriol, I cannot change anything on that page. I can set up the string, but I cannot change the way the data input page is formatted. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @AaronThomas http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/41wuzuc9/ check it and let me know what exactly you want. You need formatting?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I think my question was not clear. I've edited again, hopefully this spells it out better. Thank you for the input!

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve something like this to save time. 
http://www.labnol.org/india/autofill-irctc-forms/21255/
The working example: http://ctrlq.org/irctc/

Comment: @RoydonD'Souza yes that looks very much like it, except it makes use of bookmarking/bookmarklets? I was hoping a simple string could do the trick?

Comment: I think it should be obvious that you cannot do it without controlling the target page

Comment: Please provide reasons for the downvote! If it is obvious this can't be done @Gouda, please provide the html (or other) standard that states this. I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: @AaronThomas The bookmarklet basically contains the javascript code  - so instead of a bookmarklet, we can generate a javascript code which you can simply paste in the address bar of the browser and then those values get populated as desired. To get the javascript generated, we will write some code to accept your string/data from your page

Comment: @AaronThomas What you can do is mention the links I sent you in your question, so others know what you are looking for :)

Comment: @RoydonD'Souza good point. If you don't mind, outline this in more detail in your answer, I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @AaronThomas, I provided the reason for my downvote in my first comment, Regarding html standard reference. I think it look like you ask for a proof that 1+1=2

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you would have a prefilled value in the prompt of:

"Input for in1 here Input for in2 here"

So for example if were looking for First and Last name
"Chris Johnson"

You could use substr() and indexOf() to find the space:

```
var firstInput = str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' '));
var secondInput = str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

Heres a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/1v2tn8p4/

Comment: Simplified and added a default value in prompt ... http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/1v2tn8p4/6/

Comment: The reason I didnt use split is because if someone has a space in their last name, which isnt unheard of, it will only return the first portion. Using substr will return to the end.

Comment: And I wouldnt prefill my own name in  a field where I'm expecting the users name

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question. Sorry for the confusion, I've reworded the question so it's clarified.

Comment: Im not sure you can pass data to another domain that you can't edit. If you had control over the page you could send the data through a GET/POST method and use js/ajax to set the values of the fields on the new page

Comment: @ChrisJ yes I see what you mean, that would make it much simpler. Unfortunately I'm looking to do this by copy-and-paste.

Comment: @ChrisJ - i simplified it + pre filled it here so that AaronThomas could provide us a pointer quickly as to what he needs. I agree with ll your comment clarifying why you did it :)
BTW In the comments he has mentioned what he needs. have a look

Comment: I dont believe there is a way to paste a string that will prefill it into the correct fields. **Maybe** if the form was given tabindex, pasting with the info with the unicode tabs would work but this would require you to be able to edit the form.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, it appears this is possible in some limited circumstances by using a bookmarklet.

For my question above, once the id of the input fields is found, I can use bookmarklet code to auto-fill in the values of those input fields.

Comment: I'm not going to mark my own answer as accepted for a while, because I'm still roughing in the specifics on this... and I'm curious what the SO community thinks about this method.